# Excel VBA vs Javascript Performance for Iterating Large Datasets

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, for-loop

I'm currently doing a project that involves filtering large datasets down to manageable numbers of datapoints that can be plotted on charts.

I wrote the following code in Javascript that iterates through a range of data and picks out the first value at a given step-size, in this case start value = 0 and step size = 0.1. This works great and executes very quickly; I haven't quantified it, but definitely <1 second for >10000 datapoints.

```
var data = [ ... ];

var filteredData = [];
var index = 0;
var step = 0.1;

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i] >= index) {
    filteredData.push(data[i]);
    index+=step;
  }
}
```

[Codepen of Javascript with Mini Sample Dataset](http://codepen.io/awenborn/pen/ZONRmv)

However, all of our data is coming in as Excel Workbooks, so I rewrote the code as an Excel Macro using VBA as follows, outputting the datapoints to an adjacent column. To process the same number of datapoints takes A LONG time compared to the JS equivalent, something in the order of 20 seconds for 10000 datapoints.

```
Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = Range(Range("A8"), Range("A8").End(xlDown))
Dim index As Double
Dim stepsize As Double
Dim outputRow As Integer
index = 0
step = 0.1
outputRow = 8

For Each cell In dataRange
    If cell.Value >= index Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(outputRow, 2).Value = cell.Value
        index = index + stepsize
        outputRow = outputRow + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

Why is there such a huge disparity between the two methods? Is there anything glaringly inefficient about my VB code? I hope this question isn't too vague!

Many thanks, Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took inspiration from cyobashu, but eeked out some performance by avoiding the repeated calls to `Redim Preserve` and the `Transpose` method.

When I run cyboashu's code against 1m rows, it takes about 16 seconds. When I run the code below against 1m rows, it take about 1 second.

I've also fixed what I think is a typo `step = 0.1` should be `stepsize = 0.1`

```
Sub test()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Range(Range("A8"), Range("A8").End(xlDown))
    Dim index As Double
    Dim stepsize As Double
    Dim outputRow As Long

    index = 0
    stepsize = 0.1
    outputRow = 8


    '/ Array implementation in VBA
    '/ Its almost at the same speed.
    '----------------------------------------------------
    Dim lctr        As Long
    Dim oRow        As Long
    Dim arrOut()
    Dim arr
    arr = dataRange

    ReDim arrOut(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr), LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)) As Variant

    For lctr = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(lctr, 1) >= index Then
            index = index + stepsize
            oRow = oRow + 1
            arrOut(oRow, 1) = arr(lctr, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 2).Resize(oRow) = arrOut

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

See the Array implementation of your code, its almost as fast as the JS one.

It will take (at least on my machine) fraction of a second for 10,000 data points.

```
Sub test()

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Range(Range("A8"), Range("A8").End(xlDown))
    Dim index As Double
    Dim stepsize As Double
    Dim outputRow As Long

    index = 0
    step = 0.1
    outputRow = 8


    '/ Array implementation in VBA
    '/ Its almost at the same speed.
    '----------------------------------------------------
    Dim lctr        As Long
    Dim oRow        As Long
    Dim arrOut()
    Dim arr
    arr = dataRange

    For lctr = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(lctr, 1) >= index Then
            index = index + stepsize
            oRow = oRow + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrOut(1 To 1, 1 To oRow)
            arrOut(1, oRow) = arr(lctr, 1)
        End If
    Next

    arrOut = Application.Transpose(arrOut)

    ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 2).Resize(UBound(arrOut)) = arrOut

    '------------------------------------------------------------



'    For Each cell In dataRange
'        If cell.Value >= index Then
'            ActiveSheet.Cells(outputRow, 2).Value = cell.Value
'            index = index + stepsize
'            outputRow = outputRow + 1
'        End If
'Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of performance issues come from bad access methods. In terms of RAW performance of VBA vs JS, if we make the same 2 code examples of mapping data into an array:

```
Const max As Long = 50000000
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, arr(1 To max) As Long
    DEV.Timer_Start
    For i = 1 To max
         arr(i) = i
    Next
    DEV.Timer_Stop
End Sub
```

vs

```
cons max = 50000000
var arr=[]
x=performance.now()
for(var i=0;i<max;i++) arr.push(i)
console.log((performance.now()-x)/1000)
```

Times:

```
VBA Average time: 1.01371899999867 seconds
JS  Average time: 1.81799999999930 seconds
```

So in terms of raw compute time JS seems way slower than VBA here, however this is largely because internally the 2 operations are entirely different.

VBA is defining a block of memory 200000000 bytes long and afterwards populating each byte. JavaScript is performing more dynamically and gradually expanding it's memory footprint like this:

```
Const max As Long = 50000000
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Collection
    Set arr = New Collection

    DEV.Timer_Start
    For i = 1 To max
         Call arr.Add(i)
    Next
    DEV.Timer_Stop
End Sub
```

This slows down the VBA code quite a bit.

On a 500,000 row test I got the following results:

```
VBA fixed size long array:      0.00933219999933 seconds
VBA fixed size variant array:   0.01075579999815 seconds
JS dynamic size variant array:  0.03299999999953 seconds
VBA Collection:                 0.10702589999709 seconds
VBA dynamic size long array:    0.60271329999886 seconds
VBA stdArray:                   7.95831580000231 seconds
VBA dynamic size variant array: 8.36757760000182 seconds
```

[P.S. stdArray is an object oriented replacement for JS array I've created](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Library). Clearly there are a lot of improvements for the performance of my own library!

**EDIT**

I realise now that the reason for stdArray's incredibly slow score is directly linked to the type of variable which is being used internally. Here I do a loop over a variant array, the result loop took 8.368 seconds.

```
Sub test5()
    Dim i As Long, arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To 1) As Variant

    DEV.Timer_Start
    For i = 1 To max
         ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Variant
         arr(i) = i
    Next
    DEV.Timer_Stop
End Sub
```

This takes `8.368` seconds to run. This really goes to show how important it is to choose the right variable type when creating an array. Everything is incredibly slower when using variant datatypes in VBA.

**EDIT**:

Linked GIST which contains test cases and performance details: https://gist.github.com/sancarn/1f92164f1b53fcd940640f680a06b426